# Edit home screen bookmark link or preserve cookies

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

I have been playing Wordle through a home screen bookmark I made via Safari. The site says the old link (that currently forwards to the NYT site) will be retired in June, so I assume my bookmark will no longer work. But when I open Wordle directly in Safari, all my game stats are missing and the tutorial pops up as if I’ve never played before.

I’m assuming that this is because cookies or local files for the bookmark are in a separate sandbox from the standard Safari.

Is there a way I can directly edit the link in my bookmark so I won’t lose my game stats after the old link is killed? Or is there a way to transfer the saved data that is in cookies or some other file over to Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone else reading this who has the same problem as the OP I found a quick way to set that cookie from https://linksandpixels.com/wordle INSIDE of a Home Screen bookmark.

Since you can not change the url in a Home Screen bookmark you have to find a way to get to google to search for the above link. You can do this in a few easy clicks.

1. In the Wordle menu click on FAQ next to Questions.
2. At the bottom of the page that loads click on Your Ad Choices.
3. Click open the 2nd box titled “What Do We Do With The Information We Collect About You?”
4. In this text area you will see a link titled “how Google Analytics uses data” click this link
5. This will load a page on the Google Analytics site. Scroll all the way down to the bottom and click the Google link in the footer. This will load the main Google site where you can paste https://linksandpixels.com/wordle and search. Find that link in results. Click it and fill in your stats.

That will redirect you back to the NYTimes wordle site with new stats saved. Close out and relaunch and your stats will remain.

Comment: Thanks Scott, read this and was doubtful, but totally worked!

Answer (score 8):

I have not found an easy way to do this, but where there is a will, there is a way. Hopefully someone will come along with a better answer. In the meantime, the adventurous can read on…

Your Wordle statistics are saved in local storage, which is set per website, so what you need to do is basically find the statistics in the local storage of the old website and copy them to the local storage of the new website. There is no nice way to do this through an UI, but it can be done programmatically if you know how. **You will need a Mac desktop/laptop in addition to your iPhone.** Here are the steps:

1. On your iPhone, go to Settings > Safari > Advanced and toggle on Web Inspector
2. If you haven't already, save the new NYT Wordle page to your home screen
3. Open the **old** Wordle app from your home screen
4. Plug your iPhone into your Mac
5. Open Safari on your Mac, and click the Develop menu at the top

   - if you don't see the Develop menu, you need to enable it at Preferences > Advanced > Show develop menu in menu bar
6. In the Develop menu, you should see your iPhone listed with a flyout menu that includes pages open on your iPhone; click on [www.nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com)

   - if you don't see your device listed, you probably didn't trust the device when you plugged it in; unplug it and replug it in, and click the button to trust the device
   - if you don't see [www.nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com) as an option, make sure you have the **old** Wordle app open on your iPhone (with iPhone unlocked)
   - if you see *two* [www.nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com) entries, one is the new app and one is the old one; you can figure out which one is the old one by hovering over the menu items on your Mac – if you're hovering the one you have pulled up on your iPhone, you should see a semi-transparent blue overlay on your iPhone
7. A Web Inspector window appears on your Mac. Now we need to get the statistics from local storage. Ultimately, we will need to copy these to another window, but Safari's console isn't the greatest, so we need to take a couple extra steps to allow easy copying.
8. Click the Console tab at the top of the Web Inspector and enter this code in the console (press Enter key after each line):

   ```
    let div = document.createElement('div');

    div.textContent = window.localStorage.getItem('nyt-wordle-statistics');

    div
   ```
9. You'll see `<div>…</div>` print in the console with a little caret next to it. Click the caret to expand it.
10. Right click the code in the middle of the expanded div and choose Copy > Text
11. On your iPhone, open the **new** Wordle app
12. Back in the Develop menu in Safari on your Mac, again mouse over your device and this time click the [www.nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com) entry for the new app

    - again, if unsure, you should see a semi-transparent blue overlay on your iPhone when hovering over the correct entry on your Mac
13. A Web Inspector window appears. Navigate to the Console tab of the Web Inspector and this time enter this code:

    ```
    window.localStorage.setItem('nyt-wordle-statistics', JSON.stringify(PasteHere));
    ```

    - make sure to replace PasteHere with the string you copied back in step 10 before hitting enter
14. On your iPhone, in the new Wordle app, click the statistics icon in the top right – your stats should now appear! You can continue using your new app as normal from here on out and delete the old one off your home screen

Comment: Upvoted for the detailed help. Unfortunately I don’t have access to a Mac. But I did find this site that simply generates a new game save from scratch. https://linksandpixels.com/wordle

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using iOS Shortcuts.

1. Import the two shortcuts below
2. Open your original home screen bookmark that pointed to https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle
3. Tap the link that forwards to the NYT version of Wordle at https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html
4. Tap to share and run the *Save Wordle Stats* shortcut
5. The shortcut copies the stats to the clipboard
6. Now create a home screen bookmark for the NYT version of Wordle from Safari
7. Open Wordle from the new home screen bookmark. You won't be able to access the share sheet directly.
8. Open one of the links from the hamburger menu, e.g. WordleBot
9. Now tap on Share and run the *Restore Wordle Stats* shortcut
10. Close Wordle and reopen. Check your stats which should have been transferred

---

### YouTube Video

I created a YouTube video to show you how.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCW4UplZNmg

### iOS Shortcuts

You will need to download the following iOS Shortcuts

Save Wordle Stats
https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/ae4ace215b6747308ab9aec23564ac4e

Restore Wordle Stats
https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/6f8a8bafb20649eeabadc84513bee9fa

Comment: Answers are more valuable if they don't sent people off-site for the actual information. Can you summarize the steps explained in the video directly in the answer?

Comment: Answer updated with steps @nohillside